# What is the name for when a background is responsive/moves to a mouse?

Tags: html, css, image, background, cursor

I've just completed freeCodeCamp's HTML & CSS Responsive Web Design course and i've seen this in other people's portfolio's and would love to learn how to do it but i don't know what it's called. I'll give examples:
https://activetheory.net/home
https://lusion.co/
The game Escape From Tarkov also has this on its main menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you're probably referring to parallax.

I believe this will help you: https://dev.to/clementgaudiniere/create-a-parallax-effect-when-the-mouse-moves-3km0

Answer (score 0):

Start with basic Parallax effect, which is just several images moving at different speed.

Then change the back image to some 3d image.

Here is a quick tutorial : https://webdevpuneet.com/3d-css-parallax-depth-effect/#gsc.tab=0